# How to undo a last pull and commit

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

I mistakenly pulled a master branch in to develop branch and committed some changes.

I want to revert the pull and the commit.

I tried this command

```
git revert <commit hash>
```

but it gives me following error

```
commit <commit hash> is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

How to revert a pull and commit?

Answer (score 3):

[git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) is **not** what you need here, despite the colloquial sense of the word "revert".

Instead, you'd rather reset the branch to the point where it was before the bad pull :

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

where `@{upstream}` is a construct which means "at upstream, as in the remote branch this one is configured to pull from".

You won't have to `--force` anything after this, since you're not changing history, rather sticking back to it.

Comment: I'm new to git comands, can you kindly tell me what is upstream and what value should be given there?

Comment: @Syedmohamedaladeen `@{upstream}` is *not* a placeholder, this is to be typed as it is. Git will then use the remote branch this local one (`develop`) is linked to. You could also have used `origin/develop` if your remote is named `origin`, I just tried to remain generic.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command.

`git reset --keep e2djke3 #your commit id`

This variant is more safer. Then you commit your changes as usual